# Pyright highlighting perfectly working astropy code as if it were incorrect

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance, pyright

I was building a simulator for planets' orbits, and pyright is really helpful for highlighting mistakes automatically, but for some reason it doesn't understand perfectly working operations with astropy's units and keeps highlighting it as if they were incorrect.

How can I make pyright ignore these operations? It probably involves editing pyrightconfig.json according to the [link in the image below](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#reportGeneralTypeIssues), but I'm a noob in both json and pyright/pylance, so I didn't understand what I need to put in that file specifically.

[image: Perfectly working astropy code being highlighted for no reason.]

Also, I don't know if that is a bug and I should report it, and if so, how do I do that?

Minimal code needed to reproduce:

```
from astropy import units
var = 3 * units.m
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that produces this issue? Doesn't need to be the entire class, just a few lines that causes the issue will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore this warning, you can do the following steps:

Use "Ctrl+Shift+P" and search "Preferences: Open User Settings(JSON)"

[image]

Then add the following codes to  `settings.json`:

```
  "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportGeneralTypeIssues": "none"
  },
```

Comment: It worked, but now it won't highlight if I do something like    var: int = "a".     Is there a way to tell it to only ignore specific objects?

Comment: This problem won't happen to me. Have you tried to reload vscode?

Comment: What problem exactly won't happen with you? I found that I can use mypy to highlight var: int = "a" and disable that aspect of pylance, so I guess I can rest now, even though it wasn't the most elegant solution.